# AWS Kinesis throwing CloudWatchException

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-kinesis

I am trying **Scala** code using the KCL library to read a **Kinesis** stream. I keep getting this CloudWatchException and I would like to know why?

```
16:16:06.629 [aws-akka-http-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-20] DEBUG software.amazon.awssdk.request - Received error response: 400
16:16:06.638 [cw-metrics-publisher] WARN software.amazon.kinesis.metrics.CloudWatchMetricsPublisher - Could not publish 16 datums to CloudWatch
software.amazon.awssdk.services.cloudwatch.model.CloudWatchException: When Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded, URL cannot include query-string parameters (after '?'): '/?Action=PutMetricData&Version=2010-08-01&Namespace=......
```

Any idea what's causing this or as I suspect, perhaps it's a bug in the **Kinesis** library?